# How to record my Yamaha ydp 143 digital piano with a Focusrite Scarlett solo audio interface?

Tags: piano, recording, digital-piano

I have tried connecting my digital piano to my audio interface using a 1/4inch cable but the sound quality is very poor. The yamaha ydp 143 has 2 phone inputs which are used for adding headphone jacks mainly and nothing else(besides usb connection of course). It doesn't have a label for left and right like some pianos do. I need to know how I can use that interface with the Scarlett solo that I have to record good quality.

I read that digital pianos are stereophonic instruments and it seems like my only option is a mkno connection which is giving me this poor quality audio, so how can I pull this off with the hardware that I have?

Comment: Does the Yamaha not have L/R line outs? That would be odd.  .

Answer (score 2):

> The yamaha ydp 143 has 2 phone inputs which are used for adding headphone jacks mainly

I believe you mean headphone *outputs* because according to Yamaha and other dealer websites this board comes with two 1/4" output jacks.

Headphone jacks are almost always stereo connections, so you are getting stereo not mono. It's possible that the reason you are getting "poor quality" is because you're running a mono cable to your Focusrite's input (mono channel) and are therefore only getting half of the stereo image. You should be able to run a stereo 1/4" cable with a Y split into two channels on your Focusrite and record the full stereo image.